# macOS NSTextfield looses focus when NSPopover open

Tags: macos, focus, nstextfield, nsoutlineview, nspopover

I am trying to make a search autocomplete in my macOS application:

I have a window with a NSTextField. When value changes, I display an NSPopover which contains NSOutlineView and the list is updated as the user is typing text.
The user can select a result in the NSOutlineView then.

But, if I make NSOutlineView enabled to be able to click on a result, the NSTextField looses focus when NSPopover opens.
If I set isEnabled to false for the NSOutlineView, NSTextField keeps focus but I can't select a result in the list.

Do you have any idea to keep focus on NSTextField without disable NSOutlineView ?

Thank you.

Comment: Experiment: switch `refusesFirstResponder` of the outline view on. This is a checkbox in IB.

Comment: I have already tried this, but it does not change anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution:

Before NSPopover.show(), I store the current textField selected range:

```
let range = textField.currentEditor()?.selectedRange
```

And after:

```
textField.selectText(self)
textField.currentEditor()?.selectedRange = range ?? NSMakeRange(0, 0)
```

If I call selectText() without setting the selected range, it will select all text.
Moreover, save the selected range keeps cursor position.

Comment: The documentation of `becomeFirstResponder` says "Never invoke this method directly.".

Comment: @Willeke ok, I use textField.selectText(self) instead now.